# Wacom Bamboo CTH-461 in Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: graphics-tablet, bamboo

I've got a Wacom Bamboo CTH-461 and Ubuntu 11.04. I know, it should work, but it doesn't. In elementary OS it works, but here ... anyone know why? I need it :/

Answer (score 1):

This device is a 056a:00da device, which should work in 11.04, while the xinput driver doesn't know anything about the CTH-461 it's fairly flexible so long as the kernel driver is working.

See **line 1469** of `linux-source-2.6.38/drivers/input/tablet/wacom_wac.c`:

```
const struct usb_device_id wacom_ids[] = {
        { USB_DEVICE_WACOM(0x00) },
        { USB_DEVICE_WACOM(0x10) },
        { USB_DEVICE_WACOM(0x11) },
...
        { USB_DEVICE_WACOM(0xD8) },
        { USB_DEVICE_WACOM(0xDA) },
        { USB_DEVICE_WACOM(0xDB) },
        { USB_DEVICE_WACOM(0xF0) },
```

Now to get a handle on what your problem is you need to confirm with us that the wacom driver is loaded using the `lsmod` command. You should see `wacom` in the list. Next you should report the contents of `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` (not all of it) plug and unplug the device to get a fresh set of logs. If nothing appears, report that too.